# How to differentiate dY(t,B)/dt in the following?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

[image]

I understand that result should be 0, but I don't understand how to get to it

Thanks a lot in advance

(ADDinfo)

I am actually trying to prove that the following process can be written as stochastic integrals with respect to B:

[image]

The solutions then give the answer:

[image]

And so however I try, I cannot understand how the equation for Yt with no dt arises

Comment: if you tell us what you're using this for, the question might be less likely to be closed

Answer (score 1):

If we write in shorthand
$$
dX_t =- a^2/2\cos^2(at)dt  -a \cos(at)dB_t 
$$
and we define 
$$
Y_t = f(X_t) = \exp(X_t),
$$
then we can use Ito's Lemma to get
\begin{align*}
dY_t &= \left(- a^2/2\cos^2(at)  -a^2/2 \cos^2(at)\right)Y_t d_t -a \cos(at)Y_tdB_t\\
&=  - a^2\cos^2(at) Y_t d_t -a \cos(at)Y_tdB_t
\end{align*}
because

1. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$
2. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \exp(X_t) = Y_t$
3. $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = Y_t$.

Hopefully this is correct. I'm not totally sure what people do when they divide through by $dt$. It must be that $dB_t/dt$ has some meaning I don't know about.

Comment: As far as I know, the answer should be dYt= −acos(at)YtdBt ...

Comment: @Alex I just spotted a mistake and corrected it. No drift term cancellation yet, though. hmm

Comment: I've just posted the copy of the solution I am trying to understand- is there a mistake then?